# How to implement this algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am not an expert in programming, and looking online i found a challenge that block me.
The text is really long, so i will post only the part that stuck me.
`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` <- reference word (r)
`b b a a b c c b c c b c a b c` <- my guess (p)
`/ + | + + + | + + / + + + + +` <- result (res)

i created successfully the algorithm that given the guess in input return the result in output.
In short:
For every 1 ≤ i ≤ k, we have that

- **res[i]** is the + character if the i-th character of p is equal to the i-th character of r
  that is, if it holds that **p[i] = r[i]**, then p[i] is "in the correct position";
- **res[i]** is the character / s and the i-th character of p does not compare anywhere in r;
- **res[i]** is the | character if the i-th character of p (referred to below as p[i]) compares in r,
  but not in the i-th position; however, if n instances of p[i] appear in r, if **ci** is the number of
  instances of the character p[i] which are in the correct position (clearly it must hold that **ci ≤ ni**) and
  if there are before the i-th character in p at least **ni-ci** characters equal to p[i] which are in
  incorrect position, then res[i] must be / instead of |.

Now from a pool of word, i have to remove the one don't satisfy the boundaries given from the result. For example, from the top example i know that **b** should be in position 2 - 5 -..., and there are exactly 5 b, because the 6 gives /..

These are the boundaries:

- if the symbol does not belong to r
- places where that symbol must appear in r
- places where that symbol cannot appear in r
- minimum number of times the symbol appears in r
- exact number of times the symbol appears in r

How do i implement this? What data structure should i use for the boundaries?

For now i have this data structure:

```c
// Linked list
struct node
{
    int valid;
    char *boundaries;
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *head;
};
```

So I have the word, with the boundaries it generated when entered. But i got lost trying to implement the various algorithm.

I tried writing some stuff for at least the first 3 point but it's really messy:

```c
void updateValidity(Node L)
{
    Node temp1 = L->next;
    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < wordLenght; i++)
        {

            if (temp1->boundaries != NULL)
            {
                // Number of times the letter appear in the reference word
                int c = 0;
                int d = 0;

                if (strchr(referenceWord, temp1->data[i]) != NULL)
                    c++;
                if (strchr(temp1->data, temp1->data[i]) != NULL)
                    d++;
                if (temp1->boundaries[i] == '/' && c < d)
                {
                    // Number of times the letter appear in the word

                    Node temp2 = L->next;

                    while (temp2 != NULL)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < wordLenght; j++)
                        {
                            if (temp1->data[i] == temp2->data[j])
                            {
                                temp2->valid = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    }
                }
                // 2
                if (temp1->boundaries[i] == '+')
                {
                    Node temp2 = L->next;
                    while (temp2 != NULL)
                    {
                        if (temp1->data[i] != temp2->data[i])
                        {
                            temp2->valid = 0;
                        }
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    }
                }
                // 3
                if (temp1->boundaries[i] == '|')
                {
                    Node temp2 = L->next;
                    while (temp2 != NULL)
                    {
                        if (temp1->data[i] == temp2->data[i])
                        {
                            temp2->valid = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: When you're saying that you are "looking online" and that you "found a challenge", does that mean you're going to so-called competition or judge sites? If you do I really hope you don't do it as a way to learn programming or programming languages. Such sites are *not* any kind of learning or teaching resource, and all they seem to teach are bad habits and bad (often also invalid) code. If you already know C and the standard data structures and algorithms, and use the sites instead of solving the sudoku in the newspapers, then that's fine. At least that's the purpose of these sites.

Comment: As for the "messy" code, try to simplify it. For example using functions. Keep in mind the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) principles. Try to do as little as possible in your functions. And use relevant names for variables. Names like `L`, `temp1`, `temp2`, `c` and `d` aren't very descriptive. Such names makes it hard to read, understand and debug your code. As does global variables and type-aliases of pointers (like `Node` seems to be).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I know the basics of c and data structure, although I have no idea if my coding practice is correct (I'll google something about it, if you have any reading to suggest it would be helpful). Many times I get stuck while developing the algorithm, because I get lost in for loops and I lose track of what I am doing.

Comment: @LucaPedersoli `Node` not defined.  `void updateValidity(Node L)` not compliable.  Post a [MCVE].